# Using ListView to start new activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview

I have a problem when I create a ListView because I'm not able to start new activities.
This is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final String[] modules = new String[] { "Modulo 442", "Modulo 433" };


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayAdapter<String> codeLearnArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, modules);
        ListView codeLearnLessons = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        codeLearnLessons.setAdapter(codeLearnArrayAdapter);
    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {

        if (pos==0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Module442.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        else if (pos==1){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Module433.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
}
```

and this is the code of the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >



    <ListView android:id="@+id/listView"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I click on the options nothing happen...

This is another new activity:

```
public class Module442 extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_module442);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.module442, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help!!!!

SOLVED

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

ListView list;
private String array[] = { "Modulo 442", "Modulo 433" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array));

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView,
                View paramView, int position, long paramLong) {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Intent newActivity0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        Module442.class);
                startActivity(newActivity0);
                break;
            case 1:
                Intent newActivity1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                        Module433.class);
                startActivity(newActivity1);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do it something like this:

```
codeLearnLessons.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    if (position ==0){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Module442.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    else if (position ==1){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Module433.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you explain me better where do I need to put this part of code?
Inside the onCreate?

Comment: yup, add the above code to your onCreate after this line:  ListView codeLearnLessons = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

Comment: So can i delete this line codeLearnLessons.setAdapter(codeLearnArrayAdapter);?
but now  I have a problem with this line:
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Module433.class);
Eclipse suggest me to remove arguments to match 'Intent()'

Comment: no keep that. that adapter set up you list so that the items in modules show up in the list. For the intent problem try Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Module433.class);

Comment: Here is a good tutorial for list views: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 4):

You haven't set the `Listener` on your `ListView`.

```
ListView codeLearnLessons = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
codeLearnLessons.setAdapter(codeLearnArrayAdapter);
codeLearnLessons.setOnItemClickListener(this);  // here
```

then you will want to add it to your class declaration doing it this way

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{
```

And you should add `@Override` to your `onItemClick()`

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int pos, long id) {
```

Comment: Thanks but this solution doesn't work.
Maybe I need to change onListItemClick with onItemClick?

Comment: Doesn't work how? Same result or something different? Have you placed a break point in `onListItemClick()` to see if it gets called?

Comment: You need to search how to use it for your IDE because it will take you a long way. Also, your code now looks like what? Please don't change your OP but edit it instead and add the code without changing the original code.

Comment: Sorry I'm new and I don't know how to use debugger...
but onItemClick will be only like this?

@Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }

Comment: Yes I did all your suggested changes but the onItemClick will be a blank method?

Comment: Of course not. I was just showing you what to change. There's no need for me to write your entire code. What was inside the method seems fine.

Comment: @user3400736 Does it work when you leave your code in the function and just make the above changes? If not, please explain what happens. Same result, crashes, etc...